# Post excerpt doesnt work

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello stackoverflow people, I need help. I'm using wordpress and somehow I can't use this function:

```
$post_id = 12;
    echo get_post($post_id)->post_excerpt;
```

Somehow it prints nothing. Here is the full div. Can you help me to solve this problem?

```
                <div id="block1">
                    <div class="inblock1">
                        <h2>About boots</h2>
                        <p><?php $post_id = 12;
echo get_post($post_id)->post_excerpt; ?> </p>
                        <a href="/about-boots/" class="rodykle">apac</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `post_excerpt` column in the DB is not empty?

Comment: `post_excerpt` property refers to the excerpt field from the database - so if you don't set it manually it's empty.

Comment: There is a [wordpress stack exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site specifically for these types of questions. You may have better luck there if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you don't actually have an excerpt set for this post. You can always use a conditional to test it, and output a custom excerpt (from the `post_content`) if one doesn't exist:

```
$my_post = get_post($post_id);
// If the excerpt is empty, generate one from post_content, else display the saved excerpt
echo empty($my_post->post_excerpt) ? wp_trim_words($my_post->post_content, 55, '...') : $my_post->post_excerpt;
```

Read more about [`wp_trim_words()` in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words).

Comment: No idea why my excerpt broke, but this still works in 2020.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to use `setup_postdata()` because `<?php $post_id = 12; echo get_post($post_id)->post_excerpt; ?>` will return excerpt if you have excerpt data in excerpt field but below code will return data from content if you don't have data in excerpt field.

```
$post_id = 12;
$tempVar = $post;
$post = get_post($post_id);
setup_postdata($post);

the_excerpt();

wp_reset_postdata();
$post = $tempVar;
```

Comment: Still nothing -          `<p><?php $post_id = 12;
                        $excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_id));
echo $excerpt; ?> </p>`