# Trimming content from the get_post_field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code that is showing the sub-pages contents on the main pages:

```
<?php /* list sub-pages content */

$portfolioID = $post->ID;

$portfolio_sections = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'child_of' => $portfolioID,
  'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
  'sort_order' => 'ASC',
);

$sections = get_pages($portfolio_sections);

$hierachical = array();

if ( ! empty($sections) ) {
  foreach ( $sections as $section ) {
    if ( $section->post_parent == $portfolioID ) {
      if ( ! isset( $hierachical[$section->ID]) ) $hierachical[$section->ID] = array();  
      $hierachical[$section->ID]['child'] = $section;
      $hierachical[$section->ID]['grandchildes'] = array();
    } else {
      if ( ! isset( $hierachical[$section->post_parent]) ) $hierachical[$section->post_parent] = array();
      $hierachical[$section->post_parent]['grandchildes'][] = $section;
    }
  }
  foreach ( $hierachical as $id => $hierachical_data ) {

    if ( ! isset($hierachical_data['child']) || ! is_object($hierachical_data['child']) ) continue;

    echo '<div class="subpagegrid">';

    echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($hierachical_data['child']->ID) .'"><h2 class="childpage">' . get_the_title($hierachical_data['child']->ID) . '</h2></a>';
    echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $hierachical_data['child']->ID));

    if ( isset($hierachical_data['grandchildes']) && ! empty($hierachical_data['grandchildes']) ) {
      foreach ( $hierachical_data['grandchildes'] as $grandchild ) {
            echo '<div class="grandpages">';
            echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($grandchild) .'"><h3 class="grandchildpage">' . get_the_title($grandchild) . '</h3></a>';
            echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $grandchild ));
            echo '</div>';
      }
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
}

?>
```

I want to limit the length of the content to eg. 50 characters (so that it looks like an excerpt), but I don't know how I can implement it. I believe this part gets the content from the db: **apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content',** ... but how can I influence the length?

Comment: You can try php's substr function: `echo apply_filters('the_content', substr(get_post_field('post_content', $hierachical_data['child']->ID)), 0, 50);`

Comment: This answer may point you in the right direction...http://stackoverflow.com/a/32609639/3518452

Comment: Unfortunately it gives this error: Warning: Wrong parameter count for substr() in... I believe it is PHP version incompatibility...

Comment: Thanks for the useful post rnevius, getting the filtered data to a variable, then cutting it with wp_trim_words did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `MooCutstr($string, $length,' ...')` .

Comment: What? Where did that function even come from?